# What is happening under the hood of mysqlimport --delete? The auto_increment values aren't being reset

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line-interface, mysqlimport

I'm trying to restore the database for regression tests, but the auto_increment values aren't being reset properly.

I could truncate all the tables before running mysqlimport, but that's significantly slower.

To demonstrate my issue...

Using MySQL 5.6.39:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
USE mydb;
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `text` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO mytable (text) values ("one");
INSERT INTO mytable (text) values ("two");
```

At this point the table should look like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         id          |       text       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        one       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        two       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Create a text file named `mytable.txt` with:

```
1, garbagetext
```

open cmd.exe in the same folder as `mytable.txt`:

```
mysqlimport --host=%myhost% --user=%myuser% --password=%mypassword% --delete --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" --local %mydatabase% mytable.txt
```

And then enter this into the database:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (text) values ("ID should be 2");
```

The resulting table will be:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         id          |       text       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    garbagetext   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |  ID should be 2  |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = Value